# Implemant loadmore in A-Z section tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

I have a tableview in my project it has A-Z section and content are loaded in the tableview according to the name field means A then Aa then Aaa in this way .But problem is that the name field has huge content around 70000 and more.So i want load more on scroll but i can't do it when ever i run the program it was fail with that following error..
exception name NSRangeException --- exception reason *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 12 beyond bounds [0 .. 10] please help me ..

Comment: Need your code snippets ?

Comment: Well your NSArray range has bounds from 0 - 10 right? So try increasing its range. Post some of your code please.

Comment: I solve this problem by myself.I just Try to insert or reload section on a idexpath which index not in bound'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hug data it's not easy but i suggest you this bellow link please check then download this i hope that will helpful for you..

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/aimtableviewindexbar

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/adbindexedtableview

you will change according your requirement in sample code

Happy coding!!!!